# Difference of using activate & directly call python in anaconda virtual environment

Tags: python, anaconda

I first install anaconda2, then install anaconda3 in envs.

```
E:\>conda info -e

# conda environments:
#
base                  *  D:\Anaconda2
py3                      D:\Anaconda2\envs\py3
```

Then I want to execute a python3 script `test.py`. There maybe 2 methods to do that:

1.

```
E:\>activate py3

(py3) E:\>python test.py
hello world

(py3) E:\>deactivate
```

2.

```
E:\>D:\Anaconda2\envs\py3\python test.py
hello world
```

What's the difference? What's the suggested way or any potential issue if I use one of them?

Answer (score -1):

Both are same. Activate helps you with not having to type in the full path to python interpreter everytime

Comment: They are not the same. The activate command also (possibly) sets several environment variables, and runs any post-activation hook scripts that packages may have installed to change the environment on environment activation. Only for very simple cases are they the same.

Comment: As far as executable is concerned they are the same

Comment: Sure, the same Python executable but the effect may be very different, depending on what your Python script actually does. `activate` does far more than simply save you from typing the full path to the executable file

Comment: @darthbith So, what anaconda bring to us on manage python2 & python3 together? I know If for myself to install python2 & python3, I may to change binary name for python2 & python3, and also change pip name, any others? Anaconda make it all done by `activate`? How I persuade others to use anaconda to manage python2 & python3, instead of installing python2 & python3 together by themself? BTW, could you post a answer directly?

Comment: Anaconda is not just for managing different versions of python. Anaconda gives you pre bundled packages that are required for scientific computing. Earlier before wheels, this was a huge thing. You didn't have to struggle  to get any package installed you could just install it using conda install

Comment: Yes, I know that, and it has some preinstalled package, such as numpy, pandas, and is a good start for data processing. But in fact I could use pip, what really attract me now is the mange for py2/py3, any suggestion?

Comment: Activate is the best way to go if you are already using conda